# Route a form to new controller action in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am relatively new to Ruby on Rails, and am trying to set up a form with a new action on an existing controller.

My existing model and controller is called 'projects', and I created a new action in the controller called 'queue'. The goal is that a user can filter projects by different users using '/queue/username'.

**routes.rb**

```
match 'queue/:username' => 'projects#queue'
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
  def queue
    if (params[:user_id].blank? && params[:user_id].nil?)
      @projects = Project.find_all_by_user_id(User.where(:username => params[:username]).pluck(:id))
    else
      @projects = Project.find_all_by_user_id(params[:user_id])
    end
  end
```

**queue.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag("queue", :id => "select_user", :method => "post") do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag('user_id', '') %>
    <%= text_field_tag('user', nil, :placeholder => 'Enter a user...', class: "users",
                       data: {autocomplete_source: User.order(:lastname, :firstname).map { |u| {:label => u.firstname + " " + u.lastname, :id => u.id} }}) %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit this form it submits as 'queue/queue', and in order to have a direct link to this action I need to do:

```
<%= link_to "Queue", queue_path + "/" + current_user.username.to_s %>
```

Which I know is not correct.

My question is how do I get the form to submit as 'queue/username'? Should this be in a new 'queue' controller to handle routing separately? Any help is appreciated.

**Rails version** 3.2.13

**Ruby version** 1.9.3

Comment: What version of rails and ruby are you using?

Comment: Updated my question: Rails: 3.2.13, Ruby: 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers from Josh and Billy can accomplish this well, to throw another hat into the mix I would suggest making this a route based off of the `projects`. Assuming your routes are restful and contains projects as `resources projects`:

```
resources :projects do 
   post "queue", :on => :collection
end
```

What this does is add the route `projects/queue` to your routes since it is based off of the collection instead of a member. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions for more info.

It is worth noting why this happens. It is because the the route you are originally posting to is only `queue` when what you want is `queue/:id` since the id is specified via a url parameter you should use a get request. But since it looks like you are posting the id via a post request this is a little confusing. Choosing just to use a post request you do not need the url parameter like Billy suggested and I also agree since this will allow you to keep it a but more succinct.

Hope this helps!

**Edit** For username usage

Changing your form to:

```
<%= form_tag("queue", :id => "select_user", :method => "post") do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:username) %>
    <%= text_field_tag('user', nil, :placeholder => 'Enter a user...', class: "users",
                       data: {autocomplete_source: User.order(:lastname, :firstname).map { |u| {:label => u.firstname + " " + u.lastname, :username => u.username} }}) %>
<% end %>
```

Assuming the JS is working as it should, you just need to populate the hidden field with the `:username` value instead of `:id`. Then on the controller side of things:

```
  def queue
    @projects = Project.find_all_by_username(params[:username])
  end
```

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for all of the helpful advice, Jason. With this method I can submit the form, however all params passes in is the value of the text box, I still think I need the hidden field to pass the id.

Comment: @Drew you are completely correct, apologies I had a major brain fart apparently and for some reason read that as if you were using a select field. I updated the answer to remove that portion but the previous principles remain the same. So your previous form, if being correctly setup via autocomplete JS should work fine.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I still would like to pass in the username as opposed to the id, but this is something I will have to play around with in the future.

Comment: @Drew you can submit the username if you would like the only reason this is constrained to user_id is because that is what you use in your hidden field. Personally, I would leave it this way because it allows the query on the controller side to be a bit simpler. I will add an edit to the answer to allow username to be passed on to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Two places to revise:

1. Route. Better to use static route for POST without parameter, and specify POST

   ```
   match 'projects/queue' => 'projects#queue', via: :post
   ```
2. Form tag. You need to specify the path

   ```
   <%= form_tag "projects/queue", method: :post do %>
   ```

   Better not to use div id, if you have to, use it like this

   ```
   <%= form_tag "projects/queue", method: :post, html: {id: "select_user"} do %>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I add these changes, 'projects_queue(current_user)' gives me undefined method error, 'projects_queue_path(current_user)' gives me '/projects/queue.1'. 1 is the id of the record. Is there no way to change this to route to 'queue/username' instead of id, in both a link and the form action?

Comment: I did not answer that. BTW, why do you  want to have that dynamic id? Your form can post all data.

Comment: I am using jquery ui autocomplete, when they select an option I am storing the user id of the selection to be submitted. If there is a better way to do this I am open to changing any / all of it.

Comment: You can have a hidden field in the form and use jQuery to manipulate its value. Then this data will be sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your route to something like

```
match 'queue/:username' => 'projects#queue', :as => 'projects_queue'
```

And then have the destination be

```
projects_queue(current_user)
```

Comment: @Drew Might need to be projects_queue_path(current_user)

Comment: This works when passing 'queue/id', however not the username.

Comment: Wait, what're you passing that it works? Do you have to do current_user.id?

Comment: If I pass in projects_queue(current_user), it will pass the id.